# JS datepicker: disable selected date+1 to 5 days

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am new to javascript and i want to perform action on datepicker.
1)I am passing a date to next page and that page has datepicker too which should be show the +6 days and between selected date and +6 days shoul be disable

for example if i select 8/11/2017 the next page datepicker can only be selected on 15/11/2017

Comment: We need to see your code, and what you have tried,

Comment: Expiration Date<input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{$expiration_date}}"> date i am passing  and in js file                                        from = $("#expiration-date")
                .datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: false,
                    numberOfMonths: 1
                })
                .on("change", function () {
                    to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
                });

Comment: i am totally new to js ad i want to implement this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an actual code but let me give you my function that works the same as you want. Try it and you will understand.

```
function DateChangeWithDays()
    {
        //this add days dynamically to the next datepicker.
        //you can simply pass static days like 2,3,4 or 6 for testing....
        //var days = parseInt($('.days option:selected').val());
          var days = 6;

        var nextDayDate = $('.fromDate').datepicker('getDate', '+'+days+'d');
        nextDayDate.setDate(nextDayDate.getDate() + days);
        $('.toDate').datepicker('setDate',nextDayDate);

        return true;
    }
```

And just simply call this `DateChangeWithDays();` function anywhere you want.

Works with jQuery v3.3.1, bootstrap 4. And it's related datepicker.